# How to mock the open function for unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've got two files:

REF_FILE : it's a file with changing data

TEST_FILE: it's a file with fixed data (It's simply a REF_FILE at a given moment)

Now I want to test this function:

```
def get_info_from_extract(mpm):    
   fid = open(REF_FILE)
   all_infos = json.load(fid)
   fid.close()
   for m in all_infos:
      if m['mpm_id'] == mpm:
          break
   return m



class Test_info_magento(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_should_have_value(self):
      # GIVEN
      mpm=107
      expected_value = 1.345

      # WHEN
      #MOCK OPEN FUNCTION TO READ TEST_FILE
      m = file_info.get_info_from_extract(mpm)

      # THEN
      self.assertEqual(m['value'], expected_value)
```

The problem is the 'REF_FILE' is changing often so I can't properly test it. So i need to use 'TEST_FILE' and for that purpose I need to mock my open function. I can't find out how to mock it and I would like some help to figure out how to properly mock it in order to make it return my 'TEST_FILE'

Comment: A test that depends on changing data is a bad test.

Comment: This is why I did a safe of one version and want to test on this version which will not change

Comment: Why do you want to mock `open` if you can use it to read the saved version of the input file? Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of your test.

Comment: The function currently open the file with changing data. But I got an other file with fixed data so I want to mock my open function to return the fixed data and not the changing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend rewriting the function so it accepts file-like object (it would be easier to test **and maintain**).

However if you can not, try this context-manager:

```
class MockOpen(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #print('mocked')
        return self.__open(TEST_FILE) #it would be better to return a file-like object instead
    def __enter__(self):
        global open
        self.__open = open
        open = self
    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        global open
        open = self.__open

with MockOpen():
    # here you run your test
    ...
```

The context manager replaces (within `with` statement block) built-in function referenced by global label `open` with itself. Every call to open() in the body of the `with` block is a call of the `__call__()` method, which ignores all its arguments and returns opened `TEST_FILE`.

It is not the best possible implementation, since:

1. it uses actual file, slowing your tests - a file-like object should be returned instead,
2. it is not configurable - a file name (or content) should be given to its constructor.

Comment: Can you add a more complete example about how to use this context-manager please I'm having hard time to understand

Comment: I have changed the code a bit to make it more suitable for your case. Once you define the class, you can use it in `with` statements, into which you put your test.